# Effective way to add Integers based on table values

Tags: mysql, sql

What would be an effective way to add an integer column when a certain value in the rows are the same?

For instance, say I have a table with scores of two different players.

```
id | score | player_id
1      5        1
2      6        1
3      9        2
4      3        2
```

How can I add the player's score based on the id? I'm not sure about the last part of this selection:

```
SELECT sum(scores.score) FROM scores WHERE player_id = player_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT player_id, SUM(score) totalScore
FROM tablename
GROUP BY player_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d899/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╗
║ PLAYER_ID ║ TOTALSCORE ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║         1 ║         11 ║
║         2 ║         12 ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:-

```
SELECT player_id, SUM(score) as Sums
FROM tablename
GROUP BY player_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY

```
SELECT player_id, sum(scores) AS Total FROM scores GROUP BY player_id
```